# Почему нельзя улучшить правку метки?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, очередь-проверок, предлагаемые-правки, описание-метки

Допустим, есть предложенная правка метки, которая в целом полезная, но меня не устраивает расстановка пробелов, пунктуация и т.д., и я хотел бы эту правку улучшить. Для правок вопросов и ответов это возможно, но для меток нет кнопки "Улучшить". Получается, что мне нужно либо отклонить правку, потом предложить свою (почти такую же), или принять, потом подождать пока проголосует за ее принятие кто-то еще, потом вспомнить, что я хотел улучшить правку какой-то метки, и потом внести (предложить) правку.

Возможно у меня просто недостаточно репутации, чтобы у меня была возможность улучшать правки меток.

Как в таком случае лучше действовать?

Интересующая правка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/202667

Comment: Хм.. Не уверен, но по-моему я раньше видел такую кнопку... Но правки меток очень редкие и почти не попадаются в очередяХ, так что не уверен.

Comment: @Qwertiy, добавил в вопрос интересующую правку.

Comment: Обращаю внимание, что то описание метки мало того что скопировано из Википедии, так еще и неверное (ELF - не только исполняемые файлы). Не надо одобрять такое.

Comment: Подозреваю, что "улучшить" можно, только имея прямой доступ к редактированию описания меток, а это 20к репы.

Comment: @D-side, подтверждаю, у меня есть кнопка улучшить правку

Comment: Вот кстати интересно, почему такой перекос: с одной стороны править описания меток напрямую можно только после 20к (против 2к для вопросов и ответов), с другой стороны для подтверждения правки метки достаточно 2 голосов (против 5 голосов для вопросов и ответов). Из-за второго получаем кучу утвержденных довольно спорных правок меток.

Comment: @D-side пишите ответ, хватит филонить в комментариях ;)

Comment: @insolor двух людей достаточно для утверждения правки сообщения. Пятеро для закрытия.

Comment: @alexolut, да, правильно, для подтверждения правки любого сообщения достаточно 2 голосов.

Comment: @alexolut я ж не знаю. У меня пока нет 20к. Можете подождать, пока наберу :)

Comment: @D-side доверия к Grundy и [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) нет? :-D

Comment: @alexolut к справке есть, но там нет прямого ответа на этот вопрос. К Grundy нет :D

Comment: @D-side, ты уже в списочке :P

Comment: @PavelMayorov, так что же такое elf файл ? Вы ещё не редактировали описание под метку (если судить по 17 правкам), сделайте вклад в сообщество.Объясните таким как я новичкам,что такое elf файл простым и правильным (не из википедии) языком. :)

Comment: @stackflow, файлы so (shared object) имеют формат elf, но при этом не являются исполняемыми. То же самое с объектными файлами, которые создаются компиляторами. Исходное определение из Википедии было бы верно, но это как раз подпадало бы под причину отклонения "Внесённая правка в значительной степени повторяет внешний источник." Как дать краткое определение, не совпадающее с исходным в Википедии - трудно сказать.

Comment: @stackflow принцип "сперва добейся" не работает