# Предлагаемые правки меток с ошибками

Tags: обсуждение, метки, описание-метки

Недавно [обсуждалось](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5935/213987), что утверждать описания меток можно с 5к репутации, а вот единолично менять лишь с 20к. Предлагать же правки может, вроде как, любой участник.

В интервале 5-20к у проверяющего возникает дилемма: что делать с правкой (это может быть в том числе самое первое описание метки), которая в целом добавляет полезную информацию, но содержит некоторые неточности, опечатки или прочие ошибки правописания?

Если принять — кривоватое описание будет всем мозолить глаз, и чтобы его исправить, надо дождаться первичного утверждения, которого может и не быть, а потом еще не забыть заглянуть в новое описание для того, чтобы предложить свою правку.

Если отклонить — автор может потерять желание что-то менять в дальнейшем. Что, в общем-то, тоже плохо.

В идеале можно было бы сделать что-то вида "править и отправить на дальнейшую проверку", но такого функционала нет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему нельзя улучшить правку метки?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6035/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%8f-%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: а зачем вы вначале написали вопрос, а теперь предлагаете закрыть его дубликатом? И почему, кстати, вопрос сам не закрылся...

Comment: @mymedia написал, потом нашел, что уже было подобное (причем недавно). Не закрылся — потому, что голос за закрытие и согласие с дубликатом это не одно и то же. Я оставил голос, буду ждать, пока наберётся еще 4, чтобы сообщество (или модератор) решило дубликат это или нет.

Comment: ок, понятно; мне кажется, ваш вопрос не совсем идентичен, тут напрашивается метка [meta-tag:предложение]